# How to configure search service on Server Clustering

Tags: search, 2013, clustering

I install Tridion 2013 SP1.
It will use Server Clustering, so there are 2 Content Manager Servers.

- CM Server A
- CM Server B

In this case, search index will be created on only one server, CM Server A or CM Server B.
For instance, when an editor checkes in a component on Tridion through CM Server A, search index will be created on CM Server A,
but not created on CM Server B.
I'm afraid that an editor cannot search the component on Tridion through CM Server B.

How should I configure search services on Server Clustering environment?

On manual, there is a chapter "Installing Search on a dedicated machine".
I think this is only to install Search Host Service on separated server,
but I think following configuration is possible on my Server Clustering environment.

1. Create a Search Host Master Server.
2. Configure Search Indexer service on both CM Server A and CM Server B to point to the Search Host Master Server.

Does this configuration work?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to configure one of the machines as a host and another as slave. Documentation mentions it in the subsections of `Installing Search on a dedicated machine`

Otherwise you, I assume, you can have your Server B to point to search index on machine A. So all of your searching activity (and index) will occur on machine A. It's configured in mmc